# R Shiny: Predict Model Outputs with User inputs

Tags: r, shiny, regression, poisson

I am working on a shiny application that will create a table of user inputs. These are the inputs that a poisson regression model is trained on. I then want to take the table the user has created (by adding rows of inputs to the reactive table) and use that as the test set for the model to predict on. I have included a sample of my code. How can I achieve this? I keep getting an error saying the data is not a 2 dimensional dataframe or matrix.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

#Create a Dataset
get_data <- function(size){
  startTime <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01")
  endTime <- as.POSIXct("2019-01-31")
  DATE <- as.Date(sample(seq(startTime, endTime, 1), size))
  WEEKDAY <- weekdays(as.Date(DATE))
  LOCATION <- sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size, replace = T, prob = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.2))
  EQUIPMENT <- sample(c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4"), size, replace = TRUE)
  COUNTS <- sample(c(1:10), size, replace = TRUE)
  df <- data.frame(WEEKDAY, LOCATION, EQUIPMENT, COUNTS)
  
  return(df)
}

this_table <-get_data(1) %>% select(WEEKDAY, LOCATION, EQUIPMENT)
#The goal is to simulate the inputs in the form of a table to be the new data set that will then
#be used in the newdata parameter to model the counts using Poisson regression

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput('days_of_week', 'Choose Weekdays:', choices =c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")),
      pickerInput('location', "Select Location:", choices = c("A", "B", "C")),
      pickerInput('equipment_type', "Choose Equipment:", choices = c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4")),
      
      actionButton("add_btn", "Add"),
      actionButton("delete_btn", "Delete"),
      actionButton("predict_btn", "Predict")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("shiny_table"),
      hr(),
      DTOutput("prediction_table")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  this_table <- reactiveVal(this_table)
  
  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {
    t = rbind(data.frame(WEEKDAY = input$days_of_week,
                         LOCATION = input$location,
                         EQUIPMENT = input$equipment_type), this_table())
    this_table(t)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$delete_btn, {
    t = this_table()
    print(nrow(t))
    if (!is.null(input$shiny_table_rows_selected)) {
      t <- t[-as.numeric(input$shiny_table_rows_selected),]
    }
    this_table(t)
  })
  
  
 
  output$shiny_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(this_table(), selection = 'multiple', options = list(
      initComplete = JS(
        "function(settings, json) {",
        "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
        "}")
    ))
  })
  
  
  output$prediction_table <- DT::renderDT({
    observeEvent(input$predict_btn, {
      
      train <- get_data(10000)
      factors <- c("WEEKDAY", "LOCATION", "EQUIPMENT")
      train <- train %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
      
      Model <- glm(COUNTS ~ WEEKDAY + LOCATION + EQUIPMENT, data = train, family = "poisson")
      #summary(Model)
      
      new_data <- this_table()
      new_data$WEEKDAY <- as.factor(new_data$WEEKDAY)
      new_data$LOCATION <- as.factor(new_data$LOCATION)
      new_data$EQUIPMENT <- as.factor(new_data$EQUIPMENT)
      
      df <- data.frame(new_data, PREDICTED_COUNTS = predict(Model, newdata = new_data, type = "response"))
      df
    })
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Move your `observeEvent` outside of the `renderDT`.  Having it inside is a recipe for disaster (and is probably why you're getting the error message: an observable is not a data table!).  Instead of using `observeEvent`, make it a `reactive` and then use the `reactive` as the input to the `renderDT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `output$prediction_table(...)` as shown below:

```
predict_df <- eventReactive(input$predict_btn, {
    
    train <- get_data(10000)
    factors <- c("WEEKDAY", "LOCATION", "EQUIPMENT")
    train <- train %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
    
    Model <- glm(COUNTS ~ WEEKDAY + LOCATION + EQUIPMENT, data = train, family = "poisson")
    #summary(Model)
    
    new_data <- this_table()
    new_data$WEEKDAY <- as.factor(new_data$WEEKDAY)
    new_data$LOCATION <- as.factor(new_data$LOCATION)
    new_data$EQUIPMENT <- as.factor(new_data$EQUIPMENT)
    
    df <- data.frame(new_data, PREDICTED_COUNTS = predict(Model, newdata = new_data, type = "response"))
    df
  })
  
  
  output$prediction_table <- DT::renderDT({
    predict_df()
  })
```